# .net framework and Windows

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have started to develop an application in VB.NET and I am looking at ways to distribute it. As I am using the .NET framework, I understand that it needs to be installed on a user's computer. What I find strange is that most people don't have this installed by default.

In what language are most windows applications written as they don't require the .NET framework? I thought most Windows applications would be written in Visual studio using the .Net framework.

This made me wonder, is VB.NET a good language to use to develop Windows Applications? (My program is not very complicated). Or what other programming language options are there that will just work without installing anything extra?

Is it seen as unprofessional to have users download the .Net framework just so that my 2-3 MB application will run?

I know Windows 7 comes with .NET v3.5, but many of the users that will use my application are still using windows XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heh, I was just reading this earlier - [Windows is not a .NET Framework delivery channel either](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/04/10149346.aspx) ...

You are correct that everyone who uses your application will need the .Net framework installed on their computer and you are also right to worry about what will happen if it isn't installed! (Many developers do not...)

That said, it is a dwindling minority of users who don't have at least .Net 2.0 installed on their PC, and for those who don't have it installed it would probably suffice to point them in the direction of the redistributable (or download and install it automatically) if you detect that they do not have it installed.

Windows applications that do not require the .Net framework are often written in C++ or another native language - don't be fooled however, depending on the way that these applications are compiled **many still need runtime dependencies to be installed**, they just might not be as big a download as the .Net framework.  For example applications compiled using Visual Studio will require that the corresponding [Visual Studio Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a7b7a05e-6de6-4d3a-a423-37bf0912db84) be installed.

As to whether or not VB.Net is a suitable language to write Windows applications in, it does depend on the situation (for example .Net may not be suitable for an application that is to be used predominantly on older PCs), however in general .Net is an excellent choice.

Comment: I'll change the target framework of the application to V2, hopefully everything would still work. I still find this .NET framework requirement stupid as applications in written in Visual studio are specifically written for Windows

Comment: @Johan You could always package the .Net redistributable with your installer (but it is reasonably large).

Comment: Thanks Kragen. I am currently using VS 2010 Express and it doesn't have an normal installer. (Only click Once installer). Do you know of any alternative program I can use to create the installer or would I have to get VS proffesional?

Comment: @Johan I use [wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).  Its a lot more complex than the Microsoft Visual Studio installers but it is free and very flexible.

Comment: @Johan See [How To: Install the .NET Framework Using a Bootstrapper](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm) for more information on installing the .Net framework using WIX.

Answer (score 0):

Most Windows XP computers nowadays have at least .NET Framework 2.0 installed. Windows Vista includes .NET Framework 3.0 by default, Windows 7 .NET Framework 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for a computer which has no .Net and you think it will take time to install it there or no time for that, you can go with something Like **VB6**, but this is an old language and very old programming language comparing to .Net and VB.Net, if it is a simple application it will give you the same results as VB.Net but programming there is a different a little, for example it is mainly event driven programming language not object oriented language as .Net languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop a platform independent application you need to switch to not-.net languages. like C++ or Java (Java even need JRE to be ran on client machines)

One other approach is to develop an asp.net application witch only needs a browser in client machines.

But remember that most of windows os(s) have at least one version of .net framework(vista or higher)

Windows 7 has .NET Framework 3.5 installed.

but if you want to distribute your application the best choice is C++, because there are still client machines with windows os that does not have .net framework, and some users have Mac, Fedora, Ubonto and ...

also you should consider version of your .net framework.

Comment: If I write in C++ using Visual Studio, would that still require the .NET framework?

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you'll notice in the answers is that it is pretty hard to define "platform independent". The problem is that languages are platform independent but the executables (compiler products) many times are not because they contain either hardware(cpu) dependent code or are dependent on an extra layer of abstraction such as a runtime.

The trick is to find out what machines/OSes/customers you want to target and then find out what the best fitting solution would be.